# Proper way to set MenuItem visibility in Context Menu?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, silverlight-toolkit, windows-phone-7

I am trying to do things the .net way and declare my menu items for my context menu like a good citizen in xaml :).

I have a listbox that contains a bunch of list items based of ItemsSource.

**QUESTION**: How can I dynamically set the visibility of a particular menu item based off a function to be defined in the Page class?

I could just data bind this to a property in my DataContext class, but there are a few things that are more ui-specific that it really should not know about, so I'd like to keep it clean.

Can I somehow bind the visibility to a function in the page class and pass it the data context and have it return the appropriate visibility value required? Or is there another way?

Thanks!
swine

Comment: It souns like you want to use ICommand on your menuitem and pass it the datacontext and let CanExecute determine if it can be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings are useful because the UI updates whenever the bound value changes. Since a function doesn't update, even if you could bind to a function, the UI would never change. The UI would also never know when to call the bound function.

Why don't you just bind to a bool `DataProperty` and then use the function to update the bool. If you explain more of what you are trying to do, then I can give you a more detailed solution.

Comment: One of the criteria for the menu item to be visible is that the user is signed in. The data class does not currently know about this and I don't think it should have to know about this. Maybe I should wrap my data class in another class which implements the data context and augments it with this information? Derive it perhaps?

Comment: What is the rest of the criteria and how often does it change? Have a look a [sample Silverlight app](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26625851/SampleApp.zip) I made for another question. It has multiple bool bindings determining the textblock's visibility. It's not a WP7 app, but it shouldn't be hard to port.

Comment: What I ended up doing is I created a ViewData class that wrapped the pure .net-agnostic data class, and also implemented the logic for the menu item visibility, which I bound to the menu item as you suggested. Thanks!